# c# uso correcto de Impersonation

Tags: c#, archivo, security, windows-service

Actualmente estoy trabajando con un windows services que tiene que buscar archivos, copiarlos a otra carpeta, eliminar los originales y crear un archivo txt en otra carpeta, estamos hablando de 4 operaciones

1.- leer archivos
2.- mover archivos
3.- eliminar archivos
4.- crear un txt

todas estas operaciones en rutas diferentes de diferentes servidores, para acceder a las carpetas se realiza indicando un domino, usuario y password, me acerco a la comunidad para verificar si lo estoy haciendo de la manera correcta, a si esta mi codigo:

```
    internal IEnumerable<FileInfo> getFileList()
    {
        List<FileInfo> listFile = null;

        var data = "dominio|usuario|contraseña";
        var credentialData = data.Split('|');
        var credetials = new UserCredentials(credentialData[0], credentialData[1], 
        credentialData[2]);

        Impersonation.RunAsUser(credetials, LogonType.NewCredentials, () =>
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo("\\\\Servidor\\d$\\Carpeta\\");
            listFile = directory.GetFiles().Where(file => 
            Regex.IsMatch(file.FullName,".txt")).ToList();
        });

        return listFile;
    }
```

Esto es funcional me devuelve un ienumerable de FileInfo, el detalle que veo es de cuando vaya a eliminar, o mover el archivo me tengo que conectar nuevamente a este servidor tendria que poner de nuevo el Impersonation.RunAsUser(credetials, LogonType.NewCredentials ? ya q un metodo es de eliminacion, otro metodo de escritura y otro para mover tendria que repetir este codigo 4 veces

No se si sea la mejor manera de hacer, gracias y saludos